# Port in "notconnect" when connecting 2 Cisco switches between them

Tags: cisco, switch

I'm trying to connect 2 Cisco Catalyst C3550 between them. The first switch is in an already productive network, and working just fine.

When I connect the second switch to the first one, using the port FastEthernet0/2 on both switches, the port appear as "notconnect". I've also tried to connect the cable in different ports (like using Ethernet1/23 on both), but same result.

Any ideas where the problem can be?

This is the relevant config on the first switch:

```
hostname Switch_1!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
vlan dot1q tag native
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
switchport access vlan 100
switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
switchport access vlan 10
switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,99-101
switchport mode trunk
switchport nonegotiate
no cdp enable
spanning-tree portfast trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface Vlan1
no ip address
!
interface Vlan10
ip address 10.0.10.5 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan99
no ip address
!
end
```

And this is the relevant config on the second switch:

```
hostname Switch2
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
vlan dot1q tag native
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
switchport access vlan 11
switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
switchport access vlan 10
switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
description PCs LAN
switchport access vlan 10
switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,99-101
switchport mode trunk
switchport nonegotiate
no cdp enable
spanning-tree portfast trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface Vlan1
no ip address
shutdown
!
interface Vlan10
ip address 10.0.10.3 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan11
no ip address
!
interface Vlan99
no ip address
!
```

Comment: Tried a different cable? Are you using a crossover cable?

Comment: Yes, tried other cables. The same cable is working for another switch (a basic switch, not a Cisco one).

Comment: Can you try using a crossover cable?

Comment: Good idea, I will try and let you know, thanks.

But anyway, I thought this model of switch accepts both Strighthrough and Crossover.

Comment: I've only ever used crossover. I have a few 3550's which I can test with but I won't be able to until tomorrow.

Comment: Can you share information from "show interfaces fastEthernet 0/2" ( for both switches)?

Comment: Catalyst 3550 doesn't have auto MDI feature. Use crossover cable between these switches.

Comment: I think you are totally right, just found this on Cisco Support webpage: "You are right, support for auto-mdix was introduced with 3560s. OP must use crossover for this inter-switch connection."

I will try with the crossover cable, then.

Comment: Tried with a Corssover cable and now is all working fine, thanks!